# Combining string arguments from input file and command string with GNU parallel

Tags: gnu-parallel

I am trying to pass both a command string and separate arguments from an input file to GNU parallel. My script looks like this:

```
parallel="parallel --delay 0.2 -j 100 --joblog remaining_runs_$1.log --resume "
$srun $parallel {python3 scaling.py {1} {2} {3}} <  missing_runs_$1.txt
```

The python script takes 3 separate integers as arguments, each listed in missing_runs_$1.txt like so:

```
1 1 153
1 1 154
1 1 155
1 1 156
1 1 157
1 1 158
...
```

I have tried using `--colsep` but it results to only the file arguments being passed to parallel missing the `python3 scaling.py` part. Without `--colsep` each file line is interpreted as a string which is not what I want either (e.g., `python3 scaling.py '1 1 153'`). Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a programming discussion, but you could try this syntax: `parallel --delay 0.2 -j 100 --joblog remaining_runs_$1.log --resume python3 scaling.py {1} {2} {3} :::: < missing_runs_$1.txt`

Comment: What do you get with `--dryrun`?

Comment: @RonaldoFerreiradeLima @Ole removing the --colsep and the apostrophes, i.e. running `parallel --delay 0.2 -j 100 --joblog curtailment_scaling_remaining_$1.log --resume python3 scaling.py {1} {2} {3} :::: < missing_runs_$1.txt` this I get:
`python3 curtailment_scaling.py '1 1 163'`

I have been trying different combinations, it will either split the inputs and miss another part of the command or keep the inputs as a string.

Comment: @antonia-had sorry, I had underestimated your problem.

Answer (score 1):

With base in your input sample, I created a reproducible example to test this issue:

A simple python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    print(f'The argument number {i} is {sys.argv[i]}.')
```

And a simplified command line:

```
parallel --dry-run -j 100 --colsep ' ' ./python.py {1} {2} {3} :::: < missing_runs_1.txt

./python.py 1 1 153
./python.py 1 1 154
./python.py 1 1 155
./python.py 1 1 156
./python.py 1 1 157
./python.py 1 1 158
```

without `--dry-run`:

```
The argument number 1 is 1.
The argument number 2 is 1.
The argument number 3 is 153.
The argument number 1 is 1.
The argument number 2 is 1.
The argument number 3 is 154.
The argument number 1 is 1.
The argument number 2 is 1.
The argument number 3 is 155.
The argument number 1 is 1.
The argument number 2 is 1.
The argument number 3 is 156.
The argument number 1 is 1.
The argument number 2 is 1.
The argument number 3 is 157.
The argument number 1 is 1.
The argument number 2 is 1.
The argument number 3 is 158.
```

Using all arguments from your parallel command, in the file remaining_runs_1.log, I got:

```
Seq Host    Starttime   JobRuntime  Send    Receive Exitval Signal  Command
1   :   1630591288.009       0.021  0   86  0   0   ./python.py 1 1 153
2   :   1630591288.220       0.040  0   86  0   0   ./python.py 1 1 154
3   :   1630591288.422       0.035  0   86  0   0   ./python.py 1 1 155
4   :   1630591288.649       0.041  0   86  0   0   ./python.py 1 1 156
5   :   1630591288.859       0.042  0   86  0   0   ./python.py 1 1 157
6   :   1630591289.081       0.040  0   86  0   0   ./python.py 1 1 158
```

I think this can solve the problem or at least give new ideas for the definitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
parallel --delay 0.2 -j 100 --joblog curtailment_scaling_remaining_$1.log --resume python3 scaling.py {1} {2} {3} :::: < missing_runs_$1.txt
```

gives you:

```
python3 curtailment_scaling.py '1 1 163'
```

and you want:

```
python3 curtailment_scaling.py 1 1 163
```

you can do (version > 20190722):

```
parallel --delay 0.2 -j 100 --joblog curtailment_scaling_remaining_$1.log --resume python3 scaling.py {=uq=} < missing_runs_$1.txt
```

(`uq` runs `uq();` which causes the replacement string not to be quoted.)

or:

```
parallel --delay 0.2 -j 100 --joblog eval curtailment_scaling_remaining_$1.log --resume python3 scaling.py {} < missing_runs_$1.txt
```